# Program in C starting with different color

Tags: c, colors, dev-c++

I wanted to make my program fancy and give user the option to change the background and text color but it just starts in different one (should be black background and white text by default).

It's simple:

```
printf("\n\tBACKGROUND AND TEXT COLOR\n\n");
printf("------------------------------\n\n");
printf(" 1) Black background and white text\n");
printf(" 2) White background and black text\n");
printf(" 3) Black background and red text\n");
printf(" 4) White background and red text\n");
printf(" 5) Go back\n\n");
printf("------------------------------\n\n");
printf(" ");
scanf("%d", &color);

if(color==1) system("color 0f");
if(color==2) system("color f0");
if(color==3) system("color 04");
if(color==4) system("color f4");
if(color==5) main();
```

But now the program has white background and red text (4) unless I change it while running.

Defining `int color=1;` didn't work. Putting something like `if (color!=2`, 3, 4`) system (color 0f);` at the beginning also didn't work.

I don't use that variable anywhere else.

What should I do to make my program run with black background and white text unless changed by user as seen above?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should change the order so that `system("color 0f");` is after all the other statements. Even though none of them should be evaluated till the if argument is true, the program sees that there are "system("...")" statements and evaluates the last one as default.

```
if(color==2) system("color f0");
if(color==3) system("color 04");
if(color==4) system("color f4");
if(color==1) system("color 0f");
```

Comment: There is no last one. These are 4 independent `if` statements. Each of them is only executed if the condition is true. If the first conditions are false, the last one will not be executed and evaluated as default unless the last condition is true.